# How to use a file of fixed size to measure the bandwidth using iPerf?

Tags: android, iperf

I am trying to use iPerf to measure the performance of my network which is  android-base and all my nodes (i.e.:phones) are rooted.

I've created a file of size 1 MB using the following command in Linux:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=testFile bs=1k count=1000
```

Now, on iPerf, I am trying to use "-F" option like this:

```
-c serverIp -F testFile
```

to:

> "read  from  the  file  and  write  to the network, instead of using random data"

However, the iperf is showing me the following error:

***unable to open the file stream, will use the default data stream***

My question is how to use a file of fixed size to measure the bandwidth using iPerf ?

Answer (score 0):

That sequence of commands succeeded for me on a Linux machine. Are you sure that your file creation was successful? Can you `cat` the file you created and check its permissions with `ls -l`?

If you don't need to send a specific file, you can pass `-n <number of bytes>` to iperf to specify the amount of data to transfer.